# csvsimple's csvreader error inside \ExplSyntaxOn \ExplSyntaxOff

Tags: latex3, pgfkeys, csvsimple

When I put a minimal `\csvreader` from `csvsimple` inside a `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `\ExplSyntaxOff`, I get a `pgfkeys` error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/csv/columnnames', to
>   which you passed 'Name=\Name ,Number=\Number ', and I am going to
>   ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

The code otherwise works fine if I put it outside.

Here is my mwe:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{hello.csv}
Name,Number
A,B
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\csvreader[
column names={Name=\Name,Number=\Number}
]{hello.csv}{}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Why does this error happen?

Comment: `column~names`, perhaps. What's the reason for `\ExplSyntaxOn`?

Comment: This fix it, thanks. I suppose It's because space's behaviour is changed between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` from what I've read.

Comment: Exactly: one of the jobs of `\ExplSyntaxOn` is making the space into an ignored character.

Comment: I wish key packages would ignore spaces in the names, I think there's no point to actually take them on account.

Answer (score 4):

One of the jobs performed by `\ExplSyntaxOn` is to make the space into an ignored character.

So when TeX is tokenizing your input,

```
column names
```

becomes `columnnames` because the space gets ignored. However, another job of `\ExplSyntaxOn` is to make `~` into a space token, so

```
column~names
```

should work.

Key names with spaces are a pain inside an `expl3` environment and one should avoid mixing syntax with such keys with `expl3` syntax. Besides, `\ExplSyntaxOn` should very rarely appear in the `document` environment, if ever.

**Note.** This does not mean you can type `\csv reader`, because the ignored space character would stop the lookup for the control sequence name.